# Clearing push notifications onClick button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've got a notifications button in a rails app that lists friends' recent activity. It has a count badge that appears over the button. Once a user views those notifications I want to clear the current badge so the count can restart with new notifications. Any suggestions?

```
var renderActivities = function() {
  var source = $('#activities-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template({
    activities: window.loadedActivities, 
    count: window.loadedActivities.length
  });
```

I was trying something like this:

```
$('#notifications-button').click(function(event) {
      count: = 0;
  });
```

Source code (outside of body):

```
<script id="activities-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <button class="btn btn-default" class="dropdown-toggle notifications-button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x"><span class="badge notifications-count">{{count}}</span></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right notifications-menu">
  {{#each activities}}
    {{activityLink}}
  {{/each}}
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="{{activityFeedLink}}" class="center">See All</a></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

I'm really not all that familiar with Javascript but really need this feature to work.

Comment: Can you post HTML template (source variable).

Comment: @dfsq Just added it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to grab the selector that contains the count and set the text to `0`. Something like so...

```
$('#notifications-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.notifications-count').text('0');
});
```